# Basics of data analysis with exponential data/noise?

Tags: robust, references

Can you suggest a tutorial or book chapter on basics of data analysis with exponentially distributed data / exponential noise,
at undergraduate level?
By "basics" I mean:

- is a given set of data exponentially distributed?
- should one generally use median instead of mean for exponential data?
  Should one simply trim the top 10% (for some value of 10)?
- least-squares curve fitting, where I 
  believe errors to be exponential?

(Ok, I'll be made to write out "it's not that simple" 100 times.)

Comment: It is hard to imagine data with exponentially distributed "noise", as noise is supposed to average to 0. Perhaps you could give more details, and get a more meaningful answer.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "double exponential" instead of exponential?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution .  When errors have a double exponential distribution it is optimal to minimize the sum of absolute values of residuals, leading to median regression.  (Normally one would not model "errors" with an exponential distribution because an "error" should have zero expectation.)

Answer (score 2):

One of the basic techniques for working with skewed positive data is to analyse it on the log-scale. However its appropriateness depends on what you are really trying to achieve.